# Selenium Internet Explorer Driver Desired Capabilities Error

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am building my first Selenium scraper, and I'm getting error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]

on the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;



public class Logon {
    static String driverPath = "C:/Users/2172633/Selenium/";
    public WebDriver driver;

    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("*******************");
        System.out.println("launching IE browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath+"IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Logon Logon = new Logon();
        Logon.setUp();  
        DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    }
    public void login(String userName, String Password) throws IOException {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.kroger.com/");
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong?? I've tried all of the solutions that I can find on the Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the extra Nuget package for using IE in Selenium? "Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver"

Comment: Thanks, but I actually just figured out the issue. Incase anyone else runs into this, the problem has to do with IE settings. You just have to enable protected mode for all four zones.